# What is the range for the DATE type in Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, datetime, date, core-data

I'm putting together an application that will require the recording of dates as far back as the BC range; can Core Data's `date` type handle this, or do I need to define another entity to properly record and format dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDate works using [NSTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW69) which is a double.

> always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

I'm not going to work out how far back in time a double will go (order of +/- 10^300 seconds or so), but I think you will be safe to use it for the BC ranges. For example: 1,000 years is about 3x10^11 seconds.

Comment: Definitely sounds like there isn't much to worry about.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is useful, `NSDate distantPast` gives you:

```
0001-12-31 19:43:12 -041648
```

and `NSDate distantFuture` gives you:

```
4000-12-31 21:00:00 -0300
```

Comment: `distantPast` and `distantFuture` don't give the boundaries, they are just convenience methods for getting dates a long way into the future and a long way into the past.